# MySQL query with UNIX timestamp field

Tags: mysql

I need to MySQL write a query where it retrieves all rows where the unix timestamp field ("added_on") is more than 6 months old.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE added_on <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE added_on < (NOW() - (6 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's DATE_ADD() (aka DATE_SUB) function provides your functionality :

```
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(added_on), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) > NOW()
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

... and is quite readable :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table
where now() - interval 6 month > from_unixtime(added_on)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE added_on < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 15778463
```

This isn't exactly 6 months, as its a bit different every year, but it should be close enough for every purpose ([converted to seconds by Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=6+months+in+seconds))

You can also convert the UNIX timestamp to a "real" timestamp and use MySQL's date/time functions on it, which'll probably be more accurate and looks prettier than having an `15778463` integer hardcoded to the query (you can use `INTERVAL 6 months`), but it'll also be much slower than working with plain integers.

Comment: To allow usage of indexes do `WHERE added_on < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 15778463` instead

Comment: Updated. I'm used to postgres, who can still understand it and use the index

Comment: THa'd explain why you think working with 'plain integers' would be much slower than working with plain integers (a.k.a 'real timestamp')